# For which value of C is the following function an abstract density function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}, f(n)=\frac{C}{4^n}$

I thought the answer would be $C=1$ as it would have to be $>0$ to be an abstract density function but I've been told this is false.

Comment: Don't the values of a probability density function have to add up to $1$? That would allow you to work out what $C$ must be.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes!! thank you I totally forgot to even think about that

Comment: Good. Now you can write up what you know, and post it as an answer.